# Help to identify this electronic component

Tags: components

Part of a driver board I have the following big black component(with WE brand):

[image]

I googled the numbers on it and couldn't find anything related.
What could be this component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you couldn't find it; the first search result for `7443551280` is [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/7443551280/1638531). It's an inductor from Würth Elektronik, 2.8 μH and rated for 20 A current.

Perhaps you tried entering *all* the text on the top of the part? The second line is a date/lot code, and might throw off any searches. Würth part numbers are always in the form of numbers only, usually 9 or 10 digits. I believe all the ones that start with a 7 are inductors.

Comment: Yes exaclty I tried both parts seperately.

Comment: @GNZ If you searched for both of them at once, even with a space between them, it will probably not find it. The second line is different for every batch of parts made, and definitely won't appear in search results.